# Equivalence of ComplexExpand and assuming real arguments

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, trigonometry

I am wondering why this simplification does not work,

```
FullSimplify[Im[1/Sin[a]], Assumptions -> Element[a, Reals]]
(*Out[1]= Im(csc(a))*)
```

while this does:

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Im[1/Sin[a]]]]
(*Out[2]= 0*)
```

I would think the two lines are equivalent? I understand of course that the denominator can become zero, but that does not create an imaginary part... In this particular case I can of course simply use the second version, but I have a problem where ComplexExpand takes very long, so I would like to avoid it. (Mathematica version: 11.1.0.0 for Linux)

Comment: The implicit assumption of real values in `ComplexExpand` does not carry over to the outside function `FullSimplify`. Not sure if that answers your question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[Im[1/Sin[a]], Assumptions -> {Element[a, Reals], Sin[a] != 0}]
```

> 0

Note that there is a pole in `1/Sin[a]`, which `FullSimplify` will not automatically discard. Since the pole is indeterminate, there's no actual guarantee that it doesn't have an imaginary part.

I am not entirely sure why `ComplexExpand` discards the pole.

Comment: As I said, I understand that there's a pole. I would have thought that the inverse of a real number is real, and ComplexExpand seems to think so, too. Explicitly excluding 0 for the denominator is of course an option, I was hoping for something more general (since there might be many explicit exclusions I'd have to make).

Comment: @MartinJ Infinity isn't exactly a real number, so division isn't closed within the reals if the denominator is 0. While it's perfectly reasonable in almost all cases to assume that the division of a real number by a real number is real, it's not actually the case. Add in that division by 0 isn't clear on which infinity it implies (if any), and there's a whole host of issues that result in `FullSimplify` leaving it alone. `ComplexExpand` is a little bit looser with its assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica is not so careful with [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate), so you could do:

```
Block[{Im = (#-Conjugate[#])/(2I)&},
    FullSimplify[Im[1/Sin[a]], Assumptions->Element[a,Reals]]
]
```

> 0

On the other hand, I'm surprised that [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) is slow, I would have expected the [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify) of the [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) output to be slow.